# Set function parameters based on the value of another parameter

Tags: python, function, parameter-passing

I apologize if the title is vague. Let me explain the situation.

Say I want to generate some random number based on some distribution, it can be uniform, normal, Poisson, Binomial, etc. Each distribution has its own parameters / keyword arguments to define, e.g. normal has mean and std, Poisson has lambda, uniform has upper_bound and lower_bound, and so on. How do I define the signature of this function which should take in the type of distribution as a string as one argument, and depending on the value of it, the function should have required (keyword) arguments aka distribution parameters like mean and std?

```
def generate(distribution, params):
    """
    Args:
        distribution (str): can take values 'uniform', 'normal', 'poisson', etc.
        params (dict of str: float): based on the value of distribution, it should have the required parameters for the distribution
    """
    if distribution == 'uniform':
        result = uniform(params['lower'], params['upper'])
    elif distribution == 'normal':
        result = normal(params['mean'], params['std'])
    elif distribution == 'poisson':
        result = poisson(params['lambda'])
    elif ...:
        ...
```

One option I can think of is just to have **kwargs in the signature where I can plug in keyword arguments mean, std, lambda and so on directly. But that is quite messy and it doesn't reflect the relevant required arguments given a distribution. I wonder what is the Pythonic way to do this.

This is just an example, my question is that in general how should I write the function signature when some arguments depend on the value of other arguments to be relevant for the function. And this might not just be about Python, it's more of a general programming / language agnostic question.

I feel there should be a straightforward and clean solution which eludes me now. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: When you find yourself having to pass around strings that trigger dynamic behavior: It may be time to create typed classes that have their own internally defined behavior. You could start with an abstract super class called `Distribution` and then subclass that for each of your variations.

Comment: If you want different signatures, split it out into different functions. Dont over complicate. E.g: `def generate_uniform(lower, upper):...`

Comment: @SuperShoot Thanks for the comments. So basically I can't have one wrapper function on all these different random number generators?

Comment: Yes you can, just like you have already using `**kwargs`. But if you want distinct function signatures, you’ll need different functions. There are benefits to wrapping third party functions in your own functions: it turns the third party function into an implementation detail and makes it easy to mock return in testing.

Comment: @LoganYang what value does your wrapper function add if it just delegates to existing functions with perfectly fine signatures anyway? If it is to provide defaults for required arguments that otherwise wouldn't have any, you may want to look at [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to wrap these *individual* functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function that returns the required type of function. Like this:

```
import random
def generate(dist):
    if dist == 'uniform':
        def uniformDist(lower=0, upper=1):
            return random.uniform(lower,upper)
        return uniformDist

    if dist == 'poisson':
        def poissonDist(lmbda=1,):
            return poisson(lmbda)
        return poissonDist

print(generate('poisson')(lmbda=3))
print(generate('uniform')(lower=34, upper=78))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is probably what I want. Could you pls elaborate or point me to something that discusses the pros and cons of this approach?

Comment: @LoganYang This is a direct straightforward implementation based on your requirement. The cons of this would be that, unless you have a very intelligent IDE, there will be no autocomplete assistance when filling the parameters of the returned function. Also, the usage is a bit confusing with double parenthesis back to back. The pro is that when you supply the wrong keyword arguments, it will fail early and let you know why.